# How can i get the last folder with first 5 chars skipped?

Tags: regex

Hello there i have multiple folders like

- D:\Images\Series\0001 Summer 2017 - Part 1\01.jpg
- D:\Images\Series\0001 Summer 2017 - Part 1\02.jpg
- D:\Images\Series\0002 Summer 2017 - Part 2\01.jpg
- D:\Images\Series\0002 Summer 2017 - Part 2\02.jpg

how can i get the last folder and skip the first 5 chars using regex?

Currently i have `.*\\([^\\]+)\\` to get the last folder path but im stuck how to skip the first five chars so i can get e.g. **Summer 2017 - Part 1** or **Summer 2017 - Part 2** from regex.

greetz

Comment: Why not match those 5 chars? `.*\\.{5}(.+)` / `.*\\[^\\]{5}([^\\]+)$`

Comment: Do you really need to do it with the single regex...? It is not very clean.

Comment: Yes it needs to be a single regex. See this image: https://imgur.com/MYApByp - tags should be album: summer 2017 - part 1 without 0001 at the beginning.

Comment: @user11935982 Are you using Java?  Your escaping syntax would seem to imply that (or maybe C#).

Comment: no just a software that can handle regex

Comment: What programming language are you using? I am sure it has functions to parse file paths.

Comment: Questions about using softwares and not related to programming are not on topic here. Read [help/on-topic].

Comment: Also if you find the solution yourself you should post an answer and not edit the question to add the answer.

Comment: why u wrote instead of look at the answer i marked as solution? And RegEx are programming related. I answered only user202729 that it should be a one liner. The language is Python but it does not matter for RegEx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure regex:

```
\\.{5}([^\\]+)\\[^\\]*$
```

And `$1` will contain `Summer 2017 - Part 2`

https://regex101.com/r/RfHQG2/3

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would offer a solution in Java, which has string splitting capability:

```
String path = "D:\\Images\\Series\\0001 Summer 2017 - Part 1\\01.jpg";
String[] parts = path.split("\\\\");
String last = parts[parts.length-2].substring(5);
System.out.println(last);
```

This prints:

```
Summer 2017 - Part 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tool supports PCRE, you can use:

```
^.*\\[^\\\r\n]{5}\K[^\\\r\n]+(?=\\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xVuRGx/1)